# Adjust HTML table to content displayed

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Been working on this and cant seem to figure it out:

Need html table to hold the contents of the page in wordpress.
For instance,

```
 <table class="tableContent">
  <td>  
    <div id="columnOne">
        <h1>
         <div id="pageTitle"><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?> </div>
         <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/...img.png">
        </h1>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                the_content();
            endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
  </td>
  </table>
```

the style for this is

```
.tableContent{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
}
```

The problem is that the table doesnt adjust to the height of the_content (content within wordpress page)

So if a user has one page with half a page worth of text whereas the user also has another page with a full page of text, the table will not adjust to the height of either pages.

To reiterate, I am creating a white content pane that will go as a background behind the text of a page. This content pane needs to be able to adjust to the height of the dynamic text in a page. Should i use the table or is there a best practice in this case?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you display this in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with all the HTML and CSS? You do ***NOT*** need (or want) to use a table, but it is hard to visualise what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are looking for from your description, but here's my interpretation of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/J89K5/1/

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <article>
            <header>
                <h2>Post Title</h2>
                <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x200/bada55/fff.png" alt="Post Header Image">
            </header>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit porro vero facilis aspernatur nesciunt repellat dicta explicabo a quod praesentium dolorem quasi magnam accusamus debitis veniam veritatis quas odit ipsam.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo maxime dolorum dolorem debitis ipsum ut tempora voluptates tenetur fuga esse dicta eos magnam sunt iure adipisci consectetur voluptate laborum nulla.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus minus adipisci excepturi nemo distinctio ut harum quae eligendi cupiditate laudantium consectetur unde tenetur omnis quidem itaque veritatis neque. Consequatur iste!</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.content {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #fff;
}
```

As @misterManSam pointed out, you shouldn't be using a table for page layout. Even so, a table cell *will* fit it's height to it's content. So I'm not sure whats going on here. Just from the code you provided you should not be getting this behavior. Perhaps your content wrapper is floated, absolute, or fixed?

Comment: Thank you for your help, turns out one of the content wrapper divs had absolute positioning. Removing the css fixed the problem!